# How does the "Copy" button work for iPad photos?

Tags: photos, ipad, sharing, camera, copy-paste

When I click "Share" on an iPad photo not in Camera Roll, there's a "Copy" option. It seems to do nothing, how can I get it to work? Ideally I want to copy a photo to the Camera Roll so I can save it to my computer. It's annoying that I can't just save all the photos, Camera Roll or not, from the iPad to my computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Copy function copies the photo onto the clipboard. You can then paste it into other apps, say Mail, by tapping and holding until a contextual menu appears that says "Paste". If you're on a web page, you can tap and hold an image and select "Save Image" to save it to your camera roll. But you can't use the Copy function to "paste" it into your camera roll.

Answer (score -1):

When you click copy it saves in your photo stream then you can save from there

Answer (score -1):

As a possible solution, I've found that if I want to duplicate or copy a photo in the Camera Roll section, the only way to do it is to send it in an email to myself and then download the photo again. That way you can make as many copies of it as you need.